# I get android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0 when I try to parse a layout

Tags: android

I created an activity and inside this activity I have different fragments. In a fragment I want to check if user is logged in, if is logged in display a layout if it's not logged in display another.

here is what I did, can you please look over?

```
public class MyProfileFragment extends Fragment {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private int layoutPicked;
    @Override
    public void onStart() {

        super.onStart();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
            layoutPicked = R.layout.layout_myprofile;
        }
        else {
           layoutPicked = R.layout.layout_myprofilelogged;
        }
    }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(layoutPicked, container, false);




            return view;
        }





}
```

and here is the error I get

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: #########, PID: 562
>       android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
>           at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:237)
>           at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2281)
>           at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1175)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
>           at com.example.drivie.HomeActivityFragments.MyProfileFragment.onCreateView(MyProfileFragment.java:34)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are accessing **layoutPicked** inside *onCreateView()* whereas it is initialized in *OnStart()* method which is called after *onCreateView()*. So whenever it tries to inflate layout that time the variable 
**layoutPicked** is null.

Comment: I understand, let me modify somehow

Comment: How can I call OnStart() before?

Comment: It's lifecycle of Fragment. You can never call onStart before OnCreateView. Instead you can set condition in onCreateView

Answer (score 0):

Resource Not Found exception would happen in many cases. Since in this case, its happening while loading a layout, i suspect that the layout may not be present in the proper folder.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Comment: I created the layouts in the same folder I created the others, let me check that link